# How to create a CellValue for a Decimal With Format (#,###.##) in OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I'm currently working in the requirement of export an Excel file by using Open XML framework. The problem that I have, is that one of the columns of this spreadsheet has to be decimal in format (#,###.##) which has to allow sums. I could export the Excel perfectly in this format by using the following method:

```
private static Cell CreateTextCell(string header, UInt32 index, object text, CellStyleIndex cellStyle)
{
    var cell = new Cell
    {
        DataType = CellValues.InlineString,
        CellReference = header + index,
        StyleIndex = (UInt32)cellStyle
    };

    var istring = new InlineString();
    var t = new Text { Text = text.ToString() };
    istring.AppendChild(t);
    cell.AppendChild(istring);
    return cell;
}
```

As you can see, I'm specifying the *StyleIndex* which applies the format that I mentioned. But the problem with this is that Excel recognizes this value as a text:

[image]

That's why I tried to create a new method which is invoked as soon I want to create a decimal in the file:

```
private static Cell CreateValueCell(string header, UInt32 index, decimal value, CellStyleIndex cellStyle)
{
     var cell = new Cell
     {
         DataType = CellValues.Number,
         CellReference = header + index,
         StyleIndex = (UInt32)cellStyle,
         CellValue = new CellValue(value.ToString())
     };

     return cell;
}
```

By doing this, I reach how to convert as a number, but I lose the decimal places as you can see in the following image:

[image]

I saw a class named **DecimalValue** but I couldn't figure out how to append it to the cell. Any thoughts about how to solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should read [that article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97307/Using-C-and-Open-XML-SDK-for-Microsoft-Office).

Main concept is using custom `CellFormat` with `NumberingFormat`:

```
 var nformat4Decimal = new NumberingFormat
                     {
                         NumberFormatId = UInt32Value.FromUInt32(iExcelIndex++),
                         FormatCode = StringValue.FromString("#,##0.0000")
                     };
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Layonez's answer, you have to create a NumberingFormat to any decimal places format that you wish to use. For example:

```
NumberingFormats numberingFormats = new NumberingFormats(
    new NumberingFormat { NumberFormatId = 165, FormatCode = "0.0" }, // one decimal place
    new NumberingFormat { NumberFormatId = 166, FormatCode = "0.00" }, // two decimal places
    new NumberingFormat { NumberFormatId = 167, FormatCode = "0.000" }, // three decimal places
);
```

After that, you have to create a CellFormat to every NumberingFormats:

```
CellFormats cellFormats = new CellFormats(
    new CellFormat() { NumberFormatId = UInt32Value.FromUInt32(165), ApplyNumberFormat = BooleanValue.FromBoolean(true) }, // index 0: one decimal place
    new CellFormat() { NumberFormatId = UInt32Value.FromUInt32(166), ApplyNumberFormat = BooleanValue.FromBoolean(true) }, // index 1: two decimal places
    new CellFormat() { NumberFormatId = UInt32Value.FromUInt32(167), ApplyNumberFormat = BooleanValue.FromBoolean(true) }, // index 2: three decimal places
);
```

With this, you can create cells with decimal values and specify decimal places:

```
// one decimal place
new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue(1.2m), DataType = CellValues.Number, StyleIndex = 0 };

// two decimal place
new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue(1.25m), DataType = CellValues.Number, StyleIndex = 1 };

// three decimal place
new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue(1.253m), DataType = CellValues.Number, StyleIndex = 2 };
```

Remembering that you **must** inform value in "new CellValue()" keeping it as decimal. If you change to another format (ex: string) you'll lose decimal places format.